# Element looking weird with animation set two times

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

So I got this pen: https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/NedpxQ

---

Whenever it "clicks", a circle should be animated. There are 2 clicks in the animation, so I just added the animation 2 times, like this:

```
animation: circle .3s forwards, circle .3s forwards;
animation-delay: 1.7s, 4.9s;
```

The problem is, that the circle isn't a circle anymore, but a blurry square:
[image: How it looks]

But it should look like this:
[image: How it should look]

I can't replicate the problem in a SO-snippet, but since I need to provide a minimal code example, here's the snippet of how it should look.

Note: When I view the animation with the Chrome DevTools, the animation looks correct.

```css
.circle:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid #222f3e;
  animation:circle .3s forwards, circle .3s forwards;
  animation-delay:0s, 1s;
  opacity:0;
  transform:scale(0);
}

@keyframes circle {
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  50%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why the circle rendered weirdly, but I managed to come up with a solution that works:

That's what I had:

```
animation: circle .3s forwards, circle .3s forwards;
animation-delay: 1.7s, 4.9s;
```

and the animation:

```
@keyframes circle {
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  50%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

Instead of calling the animation twice, I created one big animation:

```
animation: circle 3.5s forwards;
animation-delay:1.7s;
```

and that's the animation:

```
@keyframes circle{
  0%{
    transform:scale(0);
  }
  4%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  8%{
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:0;
  }
  92%{
    transform:scale(0);
    opacity:0;
  }
  96%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(1);
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

So the initial animation duration of 0.3s is now equal to 8% and the animation delay between the animations is equal to the 74% of nothing in the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [animation-iteration-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) property, like so:

```
animation: circle .3s forwards;
animation-iteration-count: 2;
```

Animation-iteration-count sets the number of times an animation cycle should be played before stopping. You want the click to happen twice, so we set the value to 2.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. A problem is, that I can't use `animation-delay` together with looping animations. So I would have to calculate the delay in percentage and then make one big animation with both "loops" in it. 
That's what I tried and the problem still isn't solved, since the problem isn't the animation itself, but the rendering of the animation.

Comment: @TobiasGlaus I'm not quite sure what you mean? I have edited the pen to show the solution above and the circles now seem to render (instead of the fuzzy square): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJdJNW

Comment: Yes that's true. The problem is, that after 1.7s the animation fires and then instantly fires again. It's supposed to fire after 1.7s and then again after 4.9s on the second "click". And if you use `animation-iteration-count` it only takes care of the first delay, and then fires 2 times without a delay between.